# SQL Server - Restore Database in Different Workgroup - Fix Windows Users

Tags: sql-server, orphaned-objects

Does anyone know how to fix up orphaned local Windows users in a SQL database?

I'm attempting to backup and restore a database to a different machine. Neither machine is in a domain - they are in different workgroups. Several Windows users have permissions in the database on the source machine and in order to facilitate reconnecting the users in the target machine, I've set up users with the same usernames (but different passwords) there.

Unfortunately this doesn't work. The database users are restored somewhat uselessly not just as *[user name]* but as *[source machine name]\[user name]*, preventing linking of accounts on the target machine. Does anyone know how it's possible to reconnect those users to the correct windows accounts? I did the usual Googling, but the information available is generally for connecting orphaned SQL users, not for connecting orphaned local Windows users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A summary of conversations around this subject ...
At our site we "drop" the users and add them back in appropriately. To make this easier on ourselves we have users in a domain group (or groups), and then grant appropriate access priveleges to those groups.

 If this (moving databases) is a reasonably common occurrence it's usually best to create a script to do this - a colleague has generated such a script by querying the sysuers table along the lines of 
`SELECT 'some appropriate text for this user' + name FROM dbo.sysusers where sid is not null`. 
He then pastes the results of that query into another query window and saves that as the script

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use sp_change_users_login - the actual call will depend on your version of SQL - here's a link to M/S ref
[sp_users_login documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms174378.aspx)

and [Troubleshott Orphaned Users](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms175475.aspx)

Comment: Thanks but I'm afraid those links refer to SQL users, not Windows users. sp_change_users_login @Action='Report' only reports orphaned SQL users, and trying to use the update_one or auto_fix flags fails if I specify the orphaned Windows users.

Comment: Ah - so they're connecting using "Trusted Connection" ??

Comment: Exactly. They are connecting using Integrated Security. And I create the equivalent Windows (trusted connection) logins on the target SQL Server machine, but when I restore the DB, the DB users get restored without being linked to the correct logins. Exactly the same as always happens with SQL users when you port a database to another machine, except here we're talking local Windows users connecting with integrated security.

Comment: The method we use here is to drop the "user" and add them back in - we make this easier on ourselves by having our users in a domain group and then granting the access to the group rather than individuals

Comment: Ah, that's the answer I was fearing. Similar I think to you, we have the db users assigned to db roles, but I think there are also ad hoc permissions, which means dropping and recreating users is going to be quite a tedious process. I wonder if that means the best solution would be to write a script to recreate and set up permissions for the users?

Comment: Just had a quick chat with a ex-colleague and that indeed is what they have (a script that is). He actually generated it by querying the sysusers table along the lines of "SELECT 'some text for this user' + name FROM dbo.sysusers where sid is not null" and then pasted the results into another query window ... but he couldn't share the full script with me. Good luck

Comment: OK thanks CHill60.  Do you wanna post a reply that basically summarizes that the answer is to code up a script to recreate the users so I can mark it as my accepted answer? (I'm guessing that'll be clearer than my marking your previous post as the answer seeing as the actual correct answer is currently buried in all these comments)